# new nest thermostat no c wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, boiler, nest

I have a new steam boiler model uh1606hsid boiler, I recently bought a nest thermostat and battery keeps dying, is there a way to connect a c-wire to my boiler?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram on your boiler, or a link to your boiler's installation manual for that matter?

Comment: c wire, where available,  is usually ground